# Angular Material MatTableDataSource cannot be found

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to create a table using [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), in the examples there is always the import:

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
```

I'm trying to do the same but I'm getting an error: "Module '*../node_modules/@angular/material/material*' has no exported member **MatTableDataSource**.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Here's the package.json versions:

```
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
 "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
 "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
 "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "pdfmake": "^0.1.33",
 "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
 "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
 "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
 "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
 "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
 "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
 "karma": "~1.7.0",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
 "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
 "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
 "protractor": "~5.1.2",
 "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
 "tslint": "~5.7.0",
 "typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
```

Comment: Trying moving to version 5.0.0-rc.0 of the cdk and material.

Comment: @R.Richards I had to upgrade to angular 5 and then upgrade all the dependencies to the latest versions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Turns out, MatTableDataSource is new feature in Angular Material 5.0.0-rc0.
I updated angular 4 to angular 5 and updated angular material to 5.0.0-rc0. (ref: https://github.com/angular/material2/releases)

If it helps, here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.5.1",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "systemjs": "0.20.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer, solved the problem for me.

Comment: Being more specific on what you changed would have helped me....

Answer (score 8):

Just Import by adding the folder name after 'material' like below,

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table'
```

This has solved the issue.hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 4):

### I had the same error and I have two solutions to propose

#### 1. Keep the same package.json (with "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12") and try to implement this

[Solution found thanks to this: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6036]

X.component.html:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Color Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

X.component.ts:

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

@Component({...
})
export class XComponent implements OnInit {

displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource: eDataSource;
  ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new eDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

export class eDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  constructor(private element: Element[]) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
    return Observable.of(this.element);
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
```

#### 2. Built another application with this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "design2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

And now it is perfectly working with the example from https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview.

My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My X.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

And my X.component.html:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

All right :)

Comment: Thank you very much, Solution 2 worked for me. 

I changed package.json and then built the project using "npm install".