# Angular 5 Material 5 MatTableDataSource..."'mat-card-title' is not a known element."

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to implement a `<mat-table>` as described in the [Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

TL;DR: After upgrading @angular/core, @angular/material, and @angular/CDK to version 5, I suddenly can't use mat-card -related tags.

I can't get all the dependencies correct to be able to import MatTableDataSource. I realize I could implement my own DataSource [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390727/angular-material-mattabledatasource-cannot-be-found), but if it's in the documentation, surely a working configuration is possible without this hack. Implementing my own DataSource would also mean losing the pretty sortable headers and filtering, which is what I'm mostly after.

I upgraded the project to Angular 5 thinking Material would be upgraded as well, but that was not the case. Material and CDK stayed at "^2.0.0-beta.12".

After `npm install` I saw these warnings:

```
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@~5.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@~5.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@5.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@~5.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@5.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@~5.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-flash-messages@1.0.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

...but ng build succeeds and the rest of my app runs fine with these in package.json:

```
   dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
        "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.6",
        "angular-material-prefix-updater": "0.0.6",
        "angular2-flash-messages": "^1.0.8",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
        "core-js": "^2.5.3",
        "moment": "^2.20.1",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
        "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.3",
        "quill": "^1.3.4",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.96",
        "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "^1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
        "tslint": "~5.3.2",
        "typescript": "2.4.2",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
      }
```

At this point, I still cannot import MatTableDataSource:

```
...node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatTableDataSource'.
```

...so I increased the Material and CDK versions:

`git diff package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
-    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
+    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
     "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
     "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
     "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
     "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
     "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
-    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
+    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
     "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
.
.
```

Now I can ng build without problems, but when my pages render I see this in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-card-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

...and now I'm completely confused and stumped. There is one of the above error for every 'unknown' material card -related tag I have used in my templates. What have I done wrong to suddenly not have material cards available for use?

Comment: Can you show output after `npm cache clean`, `npm install` ?

Comment: Did you import `MatCardModule`?

Comment: Edric, the solution is that I was not importing MatCardModule...such a simple oversight on my part! Just for future reference, what is the concept behind why mat-card tags worked fine before, when I was at a lower version of Material and CDK? Some change in one of those packages that required explicitly importing MatCardModule?

Answer (score 14):

In hopes that this will help someone in the same situation: the solution was not directly related to package dependencies. I was not importing MatCardModule in @NgModule imports.

Such an obvious answer! ...but, I will have to check change logs and documentation to find why that import was not required before, when I was at a lower version of CDK and Material. The template parse errors only showed up after jumping to a (much) higher version.

Comment: strange. I imported it, and also declared my component in @NgModule but have still the error when I run "npm run test" Failed: Template parse errors:
'mat-card-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: Did you find any thing @Suisse